# Ruby bundle install failing to use pg

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gitlab

I am following the instructions on the Arch Linux wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gitlab). I made it to the part where I have to run `sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install`. Every time I do, I get:

```
...
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I tried running the command `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`, which shows that it installed successfully:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.4
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.4
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.18.4
Done installing documentation for pg after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then I ran `bundle install` again, which still shows `Make sure that gem install pg -v '0.18.4' succeeds before bundling.`.

#### What I have tried:

I have tried running `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` as my own user, as root, and as gitlab. I even tried with the flag `--no-user-install`.

Sorry if there is a simple answer. I am not very good at ruby; just trying to install gitlab.

#### Edit 1:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux nas 4.5.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 11 22:21:28 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Where is your bundler installed `which bundle`?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/bundle`

Comment: you can try to install gem with version like this ->  gem install pg

Comment: What happens if you run sudo -u gitlab -H gem install pg -v '0.18.4' , and then sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install ? Also, does the output of  sudo -u gitlab -H bundle list include pg ?

Comment: Do you get any results with sudo -u gitlab -H gem list pg?

Comment: which ruby used?  if you use rvm ,"rvm use 2.3.0",then bundle install. I guess the gem is not match the ruby version(default or system).

Answer (score 1):

If you've already run bundler with `sudo`, weird things can happen.

Two possible solutions:

1. Have bundler do a `--system` install. Ex: `sudo bundle install --system`
2. Delete the `.bundle` dir. (Consider backing it up first) and then run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` such that gems are saved in the local project and not system wide.

Comment: Your second suggestion seems to have fixed my problems. Thank you very much.